# Difference between $scope and this in controller context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing an online course on AngularJS and they suggest to write controllers like this:

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("TestController", function() {
    this.printable = "Hello, World";
});
```

**View:**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <h1>{{ test.printable }}</h1>
</div>
```

Which is odd, as every other tutorial I've read suggests to write the controller as:

```
app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.printable = "Hello, World";
});
```

What's the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: it would be usefull to name the course you are following so we know more about the context.

Comment: Thanks @ErikKronberg - that's much better than the other answers I could find!

Comment: @RGraham yeah it's a great answer!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the scope of the object you're interacting with. `$scope` is an object injected into your controller. Your controller is an object representative of a given piece of your angular application.

Earlier on in Angular, controllers weren't objects. They are now.

You should be fine going either way (if you're concerned about which is correct), but `controller as` is a little more concise.